# Escape string and split it right after

Tags: python, regex, split

i've the following code:

```
import re

key = re.escape('#one #two #some #tests #are #done')
print(key)
key = key.split()
print(key)
```

and the following output:

```
\#one\ \#two\ \#some\ \#tests\ \#are\ \#done
['\\#one\\', '\\#two\\', '\\#some\\', '\\#tests\\', '\\#are\\', '\\#done']
```

How come the backslashes are duplicated? I just want them once in my list, because i would like to use this list in a regular expression.

Thanks in advance! John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* only one backslash each, but when printing the `repr` of the strings, they are duplicated (escaped) - just as you would need to duplicate them when using a string to build a regex. So everything is fine.

For example:

```
>>> len("\\")
1
>>> len("\\n")
2
>>> len("\n")
1
>>> print "\\n"
\n
>>> print "\n"


>>>
```

Comment: Aww i see, thanks! Another short question: Is there a way to tell `re.escape` not to escape the whitespaces?

Comment: @JohnSmith: No, `re.escape()` [simply smacks a backslash in front of every non-alphanumeric character](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape). It's a bit overkill, but it shouldn't hurt. In fact, escaping whitespace is necessary if you use `re.VERBOSE` when compiling the regex.

Comment: In your case, it does hurt, but you could easily fix that be switching the operations around: First split, then escape: `key = [re.escape(item) for item in key.split()]`.

Answer (score 1):

The \ character is an escape character, that is a character that changes the meaning of the subsequent character[s]. For example the "n" character is simply an "n". But if you escape it like "\n" it becomes the "newline" character. So, if you need to use a \ literal, you need to escape it with... itself: \\

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes are not duplicated. To realize this, try to do:

```
for element in key:
    print element
```

And you will see this output:

```
\#one\
\#two\
\#some\
\#tests\
\#are\
\#done
```

When you have printed whole list, the python used representation where strings are printed not as they are, but they are printed as python expression (notice the quotes "", they are not in the strings)

To actually encode string containing backslash, you need to duplicate that backslash. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a list to a string (e.g. to print it), it calls `repr` on each object contained in the list. That's why you get the quotes and extra backslashes in your second line of output. Try this:

```
s = "\\a string with an escaped backslash"
print s       # prints: \a string with an escaped backslash
print repr(s) # prints: '\\a string with an escaped backslash'
```

The `repr` call puts quotes around the string, and shows the backslash escapes.